# Register Workflow manager to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

Want to do the opposite operation to this :

> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite http:// my_site_name
>   -WorkflowHostUri http://host_name :12291 -AllowOAuthHttp

Because I have an error message :

> "the association already exist"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Their is no Opposite of register workflow command,You have to run the same command with -force parameter and it will un registered it from old site and re register it with new site.

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite http:// my_site_name -WorkflowHostUri http://host_name :12291 -AllowOAuthHttp -force
```